# Homology as categorification of Euler characteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I am trying to understand:

> "Thus, the homology of a manifold M can be seen, in a sense, as a
>   categorification of its Euler characteristic: a more sophisticated and
>   richly structured bearer of information, from which the Euler
>   characteristic can be distilled in some natural way."

Source: http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6075

I dont know any category theory besides seeing the definition of a category, but could someone explain how one arrives at the homology from categorification of Euler characteristic?

Comment: You may like to read at least the introduction to Baez and Dolan's *Categorification' https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802029

Answer (score 0):

Topological invariants are great, they allow one to distinguish topological spaces. But one might want to do more with topological spaces: One might wonder if one topological space embeds into another for example.

It is then handy if the invariants play nicely with maps. Homology does this, it not only attaches invariants to spaces (the homology groups), but also maps between spaces induce maps between the invariants. This allows one in many situations to conclude more than only the invariants themselves would give information to.

The Euler characteristic is just a number, but the homology groups are *groups*. Maps between spaces induce maps between the groups. This is very useful!

Comment: But how is this done using a process of categorification?

Comment: I think the use of the phrase "in a sense" is meant to make this a vague comparison rather than one that is precise. It's possible that the statement can be made precise, but it probably needs many more qualifying terms and careful setup in order to make it a true statement. The author is trying to give some intuition.

Comment: I don't think there is a natural way of categorifying something. There is often an obvious map the other way around, to decategorify. For homology this to  the betti numbers and torsion numbers and only retain that information.